# Django HttpResponseForbidden raised without calling view function

Tags: python, django, http

I am writing a django server. A really weird situation occurred -- when I tried to test it out, I `POST` to one of the url, only `process_request` middleware was hit, while both `process_view` and view function that corresponds to that url are not hit. The process somehow stopped in the middle and a `HTTP 403` is returned to the client. Also, with the same url (and the same view function) I `GET` it instead in the other time, and the process went out smoothly without error reported. All other view functions/url work fine.

The server is kinda big, so I am not going to show all of it here; however, I have only two costumed `middlewares` -- `process_request` and `process_view`, and as I have said, only the `process_request` it's called; the it doesn't return `HttpResponseForbidden`.

Here are the installed `middlewares`:

```
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'ttam_container.ttam.middlewares.authentication.Authentication'
```

and here are the installed apps:

```
'django_concurrent_test_server',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'ttam_container.ttam',
'ttam_container.ui'
```

Any idea what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Could you show your `view` and `template`?

Comment: it's not a html form, hence no `template` ...

Answer (score 1):

May be it's because of you forgot include csrf token in request.
If you using html form, include csrf_token tag in it

```
<form ...
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
```

If you use ajax request - read the documentation how to use ajax and csrf protection https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/